# SoapClient -> Problema com codificação(Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence)

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, soap, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Estou realizando um requisição a um webservice com PHP(SoapClient), e quando possuo caracteres especiais, esta ocorrendo erro/desformatação.

**O que já tentei:**

Colocar o parâmetro `'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1'` ou `'encoding'=>'UTF-8'`.

Tentei também colocar `utf8_encode` / `utf8_decode`.

Tentei usar o `iconv` e nada.

**O que acontece:**

As vezes não consegue fazer a requisição, as vezes faz porém lá no servidor fica desconfigurado ou com "?" ou sem o caracter com acentuação.

**Também ocorrem os erros:**

> Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
>
> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '2 teste \xe1...' is not a valid utf-8
>   string

O que não tentei:

Não tentei utilizar as funções `mb( Multibyte String )`, porque não esta habilitado, como estou no trabalho, é uma novela pedir para habilitar.

Por esse motivo, gostaria de saber se a única saída é utilizar uma função mb. Tentei todas as dicas possíveis que encontrei por ai e nada funcionou 100%.